# Compiling and Linking Cuda and Clang to support c++20 on Host Code

Tags: c++, cuda, c++20, clang++

I am trying to compile, link and execute a simple Cuda example using Clang instead of Gcc. The general idea behind using Clang is to allow c++20 in Host Code and more compiler optimizations using the llvm/clang stack.

I looked at the following sources:
[llvm docs](https://llvm.org/docs/CompileCudaWithLLVM.html)
[google paper about gpucc](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/2854038.2854041)
This example is from the llvm documents about compiling cuda with clang

```
     #include <iostream>

      __global__ void axpy(float a, float* x, float* y) {
     y[threadIdx.x] = a * x[threadIdx.x];
     }

     int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const int kDataLen = 4;

    float a = 2.0f;
    float host_x[kDataLen] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f};
    float host_y[kDataLen];

    // Copy input data to device.
   float* device_x;
   float* device_y;
   cudaMalloc(&device_x, kDataLen * sizeof(float));
   cudaMalloc(&device_y, kDataLen * sizeof(float));
   cudaMemcpy(device_x, host_x, kDataLen * sizeof(float),
         cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

   // Launch the kernel.
   axpy<<<1, kDataLen>>>(a, device_x, device_y);

   // Copy output data to host.
   cudaDeviceSynchronize();
   cudaMemcpy(host_y, device_y, kDataLen * sizeof(float),
         cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  // Print the results.
  for (int i = 0; i < kDataLen; ++i) {
  std::cout << "y[" << i << "] = " << host_y[i] << "\n";
  }

 cudaDeviceReset();
  return 0;
  }
```

The Command to compile and link used is:

```
clang++-12 axpy.cu -o axpy --cuda-gpu-arch=sm_72     
-L/usr/local/cuda-11.4/lib64 -lcudart -ldl -lrt -pthread axpy.cu 
--cuda-path=/usr/local/cuda-11 --no-cuda-version-check
```

The output indicates that it successfully compiles but fails to link:

```
clang: warning: Unknown CUDA version. cuda.h: CUDA_VERSION=11040. Assuming the l                                                                                              atest supported version 10.1 [-Wunknown-cuda-version]
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/axpy-35c781.o: in function `__device_stub__axpy(float, float*,                                                                                            float*)':
axpy.cu:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__device_stub__axpy(float, float*,                                                                                          float*)'; /tmp/axpy-c82a7d.o:axpy.cu:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/axpy-35c781.o: in function `main':
axpy.cu:(.text+0xa0): multiple definition of `main'; /tmp/axpy-c82a7d.o:axpy.cu:                                                                                          (.text+0xa0): first defined here
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The error seems to indicate that clang is doing multiple passes over the code to link and wrongfully includes main twice.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 Kernel 5.40
Cuda: 11.4
Clang (tried 11/12/13)

I would be grateful for any hints how to get CUDA and Clang working together. Things I have tried so far: Different Clang versions 11/12/13. Different Cuda Versions 11.2/11.4.

Comment: "warning: Unknown CUDA version. cuda.h: CUDA_VERSION=11040" is a pretty straightforward error. Anytime you see that Clang is telling you you have the wrong CUDA toolkit version installed. The code itself [is fine](https://godbolt.org/z/b1fMc61qY) and the Clang installation on godbolt handles it OK. So this is a problem with your clang setup and nothing else as best as I can tell

Comment: Maybe the only problem is that you pass `axpy.cu` twice in your compile command.

Comment: That was it. thank you.

Comment: `warning: Unknown CUDA version. cuda.h: CUDA_VERSION=11040` is to warn users that clang developers (i.e. myself) didn't look yet at what's in the new CUDA version. CUDA headers were never intended to be compilable by anything other than NVCC, so clang has to apply *a lot* of preprocessor magic to make those headers work. With a new CUDA version all bets are off. Recent CUDA version worked reasonable well, but it's a YMMV situation with every new one. If clang works with CUDA-11.4 in your case, you can disable the warning and carry on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The output indicates that it successfully compiles but fails to link:

```
axpy.cu:(.text+0xa0): multiple definition of `main';
```

This seems to have been sorted in the comments:

> Maybe the only problem is that you pass axpy.cu twice in your compile command.

```
clang++-12 axpy.cu -o axpy --cuda-gpu-arch=sm_72 -L/usr/local/cuda-11.4/lib64 -lcudart -ldl -lrt -pthread axpy.cu --cuda-path=/usr/local/cuda-11 --no-cuda-version-check
           ^^^^^^^                                                                                        ^^^^^^^
```

> That was it. thank you.